# reactablefmtr equivalent in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-table

[reactablefmtr](https://kcuilla.github.io/reactablefmtr/articles/reactablefmtr_cookbook.html) package in R is based on reactjs' [react table](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/) to create amazing tables. But `reactablefmtr` provides phenomenal customizations/add-ons/features/visualization over `react table`(as shown [here](https://kcuilla.github.io/reactablefmtr/articles/reactablefmtr_cookbook.html)). Is there any package in reactjs at all which can provide such amazing customizations like `reactablefmtr`? I couldn't find anything close to reactablefmtr even after searching lot.
(Note: i totally understand that `react table` is super flexible and so on , but i'm really looking for an out of box package like reactablefmtr for such sophisticated customizations)